# When changing layout in Xfce, caps lock is always on

Tags: keyboard, xfce, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

I have a US layout on my keyboard, but since I'm from Finland sometimes I have to use letters ä and ö. On Windows it was easy, just change the keyboard layout with <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> shortcut. A few weeks ago I switched to Ubuntu and on GNOME I had no problem, but now that I'm trying out Xfce it doesn't work.

When I go to **Settings** and set Finnish to second keyboard layout and shortcut to <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, it changes it like it should. However after changing to Finnish, caps lock is always on.

I have added this to Xmodmap:

```
! CapsLock -> Mode_switch
keycode 66 = Mode_switch

keycode 44 = j J Down
keycode 45 = k K Up
keycode 43 = h H Left
keycode 46 = l L Right
```

So I can use hjkl as arrow keys. But because caps is always on when I'm using fin layout, I can't use those keys at all. This also prevents me from changing back to the US layout with <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

How can I fix this? My keyboard is Magiforce with 68-key layout, but in settings I have "Generic 105-key (Intl) Pc" as model because there isn't a 68-key model option. Works fine when using US layout but not when using Fin layout.